# Cursor Android Studio Obtener datos

Tags: java, android

Tengo el siguiente Cursor que obtiene el teléfono y el número de la agenda

```
Spinner imgpayment = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.imgpayment);
Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[]{ContactsContract.Data._ID, ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
                     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE},
                     ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +
                     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND " +
                     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " IS NOT NULL", null,
                     ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
startManagingCursor(mCursor);
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    mCursor, // cursor
                    new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER}, // cursor
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}
            );
imgpayment.setAdapter(adapter);

mCursor.moveToFirst();
while (!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
    contactos.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("DISPLAY_NAME"))); //add the item
    mCursor.moveToNext();
}
while (!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
    contactosCel.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("NUMBER"))); //add the item
    mCursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Este cursor obtiene los 2 datos bien, pero a la hora de obtener el número y el nombre por separado a 2 ArrayList separados, obtengo el nombre correctamente pero el teléfono se me hace imposible alguna ayuda ?

Al intentar hacer

```
(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("NUMBER")))
```

me sale asi [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero con "display_name" si me sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el cursor si toma los 2 datos , porque al mostrar el cursor en un adaptercursor aparecen el nombre con el telefono

Comment: puedes moverte el primer elemento al terminar el primer while: mCursor.moveToFirst(); pero lo correcto es obtener los datos dentro del mismo bucle que lee los datos dentro del cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que realizas aquí es incorrecto ya que en al terminar el primer `while` terminaste de recorrer todos los elementos que se encuentran en el Cursor!.

Como una opción puedes moverte al primer elemento del cursor al terminar el primer `while` :

```
mCursor.moveToFirst();
while (!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
    contactos.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("DISPLAY_NAME"))); //add the item
    mCursor.moveToNext();
}

mCursor.moveToFirst() //*inicia en primer posición.

while (!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
    contactosCel.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("NUMBER"))); //add the item
    mCursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Pero lo común y correcto es obtener los datos dentro del mismo `while` que lee los datos del cursor:

```
mCursor.moveToFirst();
while (!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {        
  contactos.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("DISPLAY_NAME"))); 
  contactosCel.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("NUMBER"))); 
  mCursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: Jorge gracias por la respuesta , aunque intentadolo asi como me decis  me da Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it. , edite mi publicacion con foto pantalals para que quede mas claro

Comment: tenia mal el nombre de la columna , gracias Jorge como siempre un capo!

Comment: Excelente bruno, que bueno resolviste tu problema, pero cual era el nombre real de la columna "number"? saludos!

Comment: "data1" aunque se lo puso solo asi ... , recien vi que podia hacerle mCursor.getColumnNames(); , Jorge puedo iniciar un chat 1 segundo contigo?

Comment: si también puedes usar mCursor.getColumnNames();, claro que si invitame, Bruno.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67529/discussion-on-answer-by-jorgesys-cursor-android-studio-obtener-datos).

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que cuando terminas de recorrer los elementos del cursor mientras obtienes los nombres, ya estás en la última parte de la lista y por ende ya no hay más elementos qué recorrer.

Lo que podrías hacer es resetear el cursor para que esté de nuevo apuntando al primer elemento de la lista, aunque lo que te recomiendo es que obtengas el nombre Y el número de teléfono en una sola corrida, así te ahorras un ciclo:

```
while (!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
    contactos.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("DISPLAY_NAME")));
    contactosCel.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("NUMBER")));
    mCursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: skw gracias por la respuesta , aunque intentadolo asi como me decis me da Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it. , edite mi publicacion con foto pantalals para que quede mas claro

Comment: tenia mal el nombre de mi columna  , Gracias por la respeusta SKW